# How to create posts with a specific date in bulk

Tags: post-status, wp-update-post

I need to import posts with a specific date.  They way I am doing it now is I import as draft, then I use php to publish, then use php to change the date.

The problem is that if I make a mistake in the last step it is difficult to undo.

Is there any other way to create posts at a specific date while having an interim state like draft and then publishing?  Can I use some of the other post status like 'pending'

Comment: which API  do you use to make the changes and did you look at the post's  revision to check if the older revision is still there?

Comment: I use wp_update_post to change the date.  I didn't think older revision exists.  I'll check and get back.